# Can an ordinal variable such as Bond Rating reasonably be regressed against a continuous variable such as rate of return?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, continuous-data

I encountered an analysis in which the analyst claims to have regressed ordinal values for bond ratings assign on a scale of 1 to 21 with 1 representing the highest rated bonds and 21 representing the lowest rating bonds with rates of return for the companies for which the bond ratings have been published.  Assuming rate of return is reasonably characterized as a continuous variable, can a regression of ordinal bond rating values against rates of return produce meaningful results?

Comment: I would just like to be very picky about terminology and point out here that continuous  measurements can be ordinal and discrete measurements can be interval or ratio..

Comment: The question here is whether the equal interval assumption is reasonable here -- that there's as much difference between Aa1 and Aa2 as between Ca and C (Moody's scale).  I don't know.  (I tried checking on Fidelity's bond yield table to see how reasonable the assuption was, but they -- wisely -- don't show people like me ratings below Baa, which is only halfway down the scale).

Comment: I was just trying to make a terminological point. My view is that in practice the ordinal/interval distinction is rarely important.

Answer (score 1):

CV may not be the best site for what is, essentially, a financial question. That said, ordinal relationships assume several things, among them that the rankings are equidistant, e.g., that the step from 1 to 2 is the same as the step from 7 to 8. Wrt bond ratings, this is obviously not the case as there can be a big shift in industry perceptions, e.g., between investment grade vs junk bonds. Not only that but ratings are, by definition, categorical. If the analyst were regressing returns against the probability of default given a rating, that would make more sense. Finally, bond ratings tend not to move around too much or very fast. This *stickiness* in their behavior argues even more for treating them as categorical factors.

However, you have left out some important information. Is this analysis for a single sector/industry or for multiple sectors? How are returns being calculated, over what time frame? Are ratings assumed fixed, e.g., is this analysis cross sectional -- for one time period only? Is it possible for ratings to change in that time frame? You also didn't mention which rating was being used, Moody's? Fitch? And so on.

Finally, there's always more than one way to do an analysis, even a seemingly simple one like this. Rather than calling the guy out for being "wrong," why not suggest a different, more powerful (statistically) approach? I haven't run a test but am willing to bet my bottom dollar that treating ratings as a categorical factor will improve the fit based on any summary model statistic you care to examine.